# Typesetting trees and connecting nodes and subnodes within AVMs in forest

Tags: forest, linguistics, tikzmark

For typesetting LFG analyses one has to connect nodes in a tree with parts of Attribute-Value Matrices (AVMs). I used `tcolorbox`for this. (See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218417/replacing-tree-dvips-connect-nodes-in-a-tabular-environment/218458#218458). One can define one AVM or sub-AVM as one node and give it a name. The nodes can then be connected with arrows. The problem is that this code stopped to work and there may be a better way to achieve this functionality.

[image]

Similar code was running under texlive 2013 (and produced the figure above) but it does not run under 2017. I am looking for a simple way to draw such arrows from nodes and subnodes in trees into AVMs.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\def\lfgms#1{%
\mbox{%
\tabcolsep0pt\arraycolsep0pt%
$%
\left[%
\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\scshape}l@{\hspace{5pt}}>{\small}l@{}}%
#1%
\end{tabular}%
\rule{0mm}{5mm}%
\right]%
$%
}%
\vspace{1mm}%
}

%http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/218417/replacing-tree-dvips-connect-nodes-in-a-tabular-environment/218458#218458
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
% for texlive 2015
\newtcbox{\mybox}[1][]{empty,shrink tight,nobeforeafter,on line,before upper=\vphantom{gM},remember as=#1,top=2pt,bottom=2pt}

\newcommand{\mynode}[2]{\mybox[#1]{#2}}


\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\newcommand{\centtab}[1]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
sn edges
[VP, name=vp1
  [\centtab{(\textsc{subj}) = d\\
                 \subnode{npsubj}{NP}}
         [David]]
  [VP, name=vp2
     [\centtab{(\textsc{obj}) = d\\
      \subnode{npobj}{NP}}
       [den Apfel, roof]]
     [VP,name=vp3
       [V,name=v
             [verschlingt]]]]]
\end{forest}\hfill
\raisebox{5em}{%
\mynode{all}{\lfgms{ pred & `DUMMY{\textsc{subj},\textsc{obj}}'~~\\
                     subj & \mynode{fdavid}{\lfgms{ pred &  `DAVID' \\
                                           }}\\
                     tense & PRES\\
                     obj  & \mynode{fapple}{\lfgms{ pred & `APFEL'\\
                                                 }}}}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture] 
\draw[->] (vp1)    to[out= 0,in=180] (all.west);
\draw[->] (vp2)    to[out= 0,in=180] (all.west);
\draw[->] (vp3)    to[out= 0,in=180] (all.west);
\draw[->] (v)      to[out= 0,in=180] (all.west);
\draw[->] (npsubj) to[out=15,in=210] (fdavid.west);
\draw[->] (npobj)  to[out= 0,in=210] (fapple.west);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

**Edit 3:**

The following works with `pdflatex`but does not with `xelatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\def\lfgms#1{%
\mbox{%
\tabcolsep0pt\arraycolsep0pt%
$%
\left[%
\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\scshape}l@{\hspace{5pt}}>{\small}l@{}}%
#1%
\end{tabular}%
\rule{0mm}{5mm}%
\right]%
$%
}%
\vspace{1mm}%
}


\newcommand{\mynode}[2]%
{\tikz[baseline=(#1.base), remember picture]\node[outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0pt] (#1) {#2};}

\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\newcommand{\centtab}[1]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
sn edges
[\subnode{vp1}{VP}
  [\centtab{(\textsc{subj}) = d\\
                 \subnode{npsubj}{NP}}
         [David]]
  [\subnode{vp2}{VP}
     [\centtab{(\textsc{obj}) = d\\
      \subnode{npobj}{NP}}
       [den Apfel, roof]]
     [\subnode{vp3}{VP}
       [\subnode{v}{V}
             [verschlingt]]]]]
\end{forest}\hfill
\raisebox{5em}{%
\mynode{all}{\lfgms{ pred & `DUMMY{\textsc{subj},\textsc{obj}}'~~\\
                     subj & \mynode{fdavid}{\lfgms{ pred &  `DAVID' \\
                                           }}\\
                     tense & PRES\\
                     obj  & \mynode{fapple}{\lfgms{ pred & `APFEL'\\
                                                 }}}}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture] 
\draw[->] (vp1)    to[out= 0,in=180] (all.west);
\draw[->] (vp2)    to[out= 0,in=180] (all.west);
\draw[->] (vp3)    to[out= 0,in=180] (all.west);
\draw[->] (v)      to[out= 0,in=180] (all.west);
\draw[->] (npsubj) to[out=15,in=210] (fdavid.west);
\draw[->] (npobj)  to[out= 0,in=210] (fapple.west);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Two comments: your code as shown doesn't run because of the `triangle`style which is from an earlier version of `forest`. After fixing that, you might want to show the current output.

Comment: Yes, I said that it only runs with texlive 2013/2015. So it has to be the old forest. I cannot find a way to do this with texlive 2017 = the most recent versions of tcolorbox. It complains about missing \locbox.

Comment: When I remove the `triangle` style the document  compiles without error although the arrows aren't aligned correctly. So you should work with that problem.

Comment: Yes, it does compile, but the nodes are not connected. The arrows start somewhere in the middle rather than at the NP, V, and VP nodes.

Comment: Right that's exactly what I said. So let's work with that problem.

Comment: `arrows` is deprecated. The `linguistics` Forest library provides `roof`, as well as `sn edges` etc. `\def\down` is asking for trouble, surely?

Comment: There used to be `tikzmark` with `\subnode` and this is what I really need. Just a node on a page somewhere. I used it in the above example. But it does not work any longer. `sm edges` is special with glosses of words. How do I get rid of `arrows`?

Comment: I minimized the example. The arrows are all over the page now ...

Comment: Also found this without  `tcolorbox`   \newcommand{\mynode}[2]%
    {\tikz[baseline=(#1.base), remember picture]\node[outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0pt] (#1) {#2};}

Comment: @AlanMunn This is now essentially a different question. Do you know re. the XeTeX vs. pdfTeX issue? Would playing around with the different driver options help? I can't remember if this is even expected to work with non-PDF .... Certainly, not all things PGF/Ti*k*Z work in the same way ....

Comment: @cfr I get the same output with LuaLaTeX as pdfLaTeX; whether that's a suitable substitute for XeLaTeX in this case I don't know.

Comment: `tikzmark` with `\subnode` is still available - there is no 'used to be'. So if you had a solution with that, what's the problem?

Comment: I tried replacing `\mynode` with `\subnode` in the example above, but this does not work: ! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...node@name \endcsname {\pgfpictureid 
                                                  }\fi }
l.73            }}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although your example document doesn't work with XeLaTeX, it does work with LuaLaTeX.  For many use cases LuaLaTeX can substitute for XeLaTeX with no changes to code at all.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\def\lfgms#1{%
\mbox{%
\tabcolsep0pt\arraycolsep0pt%
$%
\left[%
\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\scshape}l@{\hspace{5pt}}>{\small}l@{}}%
#1%
\end{tabular}%
\rule{0mm}{5mm}%
\right]%
$%
}%
\vspace{1mm}%
}


\newcommand{\mynode}[2]%
{\tikz[baseline=(#1.base), remember picture]\node[outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0pt] (#1) {#2};}

\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}

\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\newcommand{\centtab}[1]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
sn edges
[\subnode{vp1}{VP}
  [\centtab{(\textsc{subj}) = d\\
                 \subnode{npsubj}{NP}}
         [David]]
  [\subnode{vp2}{VP}
     [\centtab{(\textsc{obj}) = d\\
      \subnode{npobj}{NP}}
       [den Apfel, roof]]
     [\subnode{vp3}{VP}
       [\subnode{v}{V}
             [verschlingt]]]]]
\end{forest}\hfill
\raisebox{5em}{%
\mynode{all}{\lfgms{ pred & `DUMMY{\textsc{subj},\textsc{obj}}'~~\\
                     subj & \mynode{fdavid}{\lfgms{ pred &  `DAVID' \\
                                           }}\\
                     tense & PRES\\
                     obj  & \mynode{fapple}{\lfgms{ pred & `APFEL'\\
                                                 }}}}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture] 
\draw[->] (vp1)    to[out= 0,in=180] (all.west);
\draw[->] (vp2)    to[out= 0,in=180] (all.west);
\draw[->] (vp3)    to[out= 0,in=180] (all.west);
\draw[->] (v)      to[out= 0,in=180] (all.west);
\draw[->] (npsubj) to[out=15,in=210] (fdavid.west);
\draw[->] (npobj)  to[out= 0,in=210] (fapple.west);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]