# Text wrap of an object

Tags: tikz-pgf, wrapfigure, wrap, wrapfig

I didn't manage to deal with a wrapping of my object. The object is made by  function (that I found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/396814/typesetting-trees-and-connecting-nodes-and-subnodes-within-avms-in-forest)), which is an LFG f-structure. I would like to place it on the right side of the page, and being wrapped with text on the left. All the code:

```
% META

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}

% ADDITIONAL FUNCTIONS

\def\lfgms#1{ % creating figure with f-structure from LFG.
\mbox{
\tabcolsep0pt\arraycolsep0pt
$
\left[%
\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\scshape}l@{\hspace{5pt}}>{\small}l@{}}%
#1%
\end{tabular}%
\rule{0mm}{5mm}%
\right]%
$%
}\vspace{1mm}
}


\newcommand{\mynode}[2] %creating nodes for tikz-lines
{\tikz[baseline=(#1.base), remember picture]\node[outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0pt] (#1) {#2};}


%DOCUMENT

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\lfgms{ 
    ~pred & ~‘want\;\guilsinglleft\textsc{subj comp}\guilsinglright’~~\\
    \\
    ~tam & ~PRS\\
    \\
    ~foc & \mynode{foc4_1}{}\\
    \\
    ~subj & \mynode{zaur4}{\lfgms{ ~pred &  `Zaur'~~\\
                     ~case &  GEN~}}\\
    \\
    ~comp &     \lfgms{ ~pred & ~‘come\;\guilsinglleft\textsc{subj}\guilsinglright’~~\\
                        \\
                        ~tam  & ~ PAST \\
                        \\
                        ~foc  & \mynode{foc4_2}{}\\
                        \\
                        ~subj & \mynode{alan4}{\lfgms{
                            ~pred & ~‘Alan'~~\\
                            \\
                            ~case &  ~NOM~\\
                            }}
                }
    }
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[-] (foc4_1.east) -- (zaur4.east);
\draw[-] (foc4_2.east) -- (alan4.east);
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

Now they are placed like this:

[image]

So I want all the paragraph to wrap the object placed on the right. I tried to apply wrapfigure and got no result.

PS compilator is xelatex

Comment: welcome to tex.se! please merge your code fragments to one small complete document, which we can copy and test in our computers. also try to reduce it that  be minimal.

Comment: @zarko i've merged fragments. but i'm not sure what is necessary for correct compilation, and what's not. so reduction is not significant

Comment: Just take the code and try to compile it. If you get an error message, then you missed something.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner yes! now the all the code presented is solid and gives exactly whats shown on the screenshot.

Comment: Try `\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{50mm}\lfgms{ ...}\end{wrapfigure}~\lipsum[1]`.